# Trying to access Ubuntu 12.10 rdp via SSH tunnel

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, remote-access

So I have a Ubuntu 12.10 sitting at home. I SSH to my DD-WRT router. I use the Bit Vise SSH client to SSH from my Windows 7 laptop at work to my router. I have terminal access to the Ubuntu PC thru SSH. So I can run commands etc and do maintenance on it too. I really want remote desktop access thru my SSH tunnel. We Tried X2go and it worked then it has quit and we cant get it running again.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

I do something very similar while I am at work. I have a SSH Server that I connect to. However, I use KiTTY (PuTTY Hybrid) that I use to create a tunnel. I create a Dynamic Source Port 1000 tunnel to my SSH server. It still communicates on port 22 and everything else is normal.

[image]

However, I can then change my connection settings to use a SOCKS5 on my localhost on port 80. Any traffic through this application tunnels through my home network and then allows me to access network resources on my home network (including RDP of my home computers).

[image]